# How to put / use dialog in an already constructed bash scode

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu, dialog

I have a source code written in bash and i need to use dialog to create terminal GUI. My  bash code have menu and sub-menu's.
i have this code and i tried to use dialog but when i tried to select from the main menu nothing happened/happens.

```
INPUT=/tmp/projekt.txt
while true ;do #a loop so this list will be used again, until the user presses x button

dialog --backtitle "Welcome to MY utility" --title"======MAINMENU======="    --menu "Choices:" 20 50 10 \
 "A." " File operations" \
 "B." "Directory operations" \
 "C." " Process management" \
 "D." "Search operations" \
 "X." "Exit the program" 2>"${INPUT}"

choice=$(<"${INPUT}")

case $choice in

    Adialog --title "File operations" --menu "Choices:" 20 50 10 \
     "A." "Copy file" \
     "B." "Rename file" \
     "C." "Remove file" \
     "D." "Edit file" \
     "E." "Print file" \
     "X." "Return to main menu" 2>"${INPUT}" 
    choiceA=$(<"${INPUT}")


        case $choiceA in

            a)
            #a place for the functions
            functionAA
            ;;

            b)
            functionAB
            ;;

            c)
            functionAC
            ;;

            d)
            functionAD
            ;;

            e)
            functionAE
            ;;

            x)
            --infobox "Returning to main menu" 10 13; sleep 3; clear;; 
            ;;

                            *)
                            echo
                            echo -e "\e[91mNo option was reconized\e[0m" #Light red color, not exactly the same$
            echo
            echo "Returning to main menu"


        esac
        #done

    ;;
```

Comment: You can use [`dialog`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/dialog.1.html) or the bash builtin [`select`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-select)

Comment: [How to debug a bash script?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/155551/74329)

Comment: "i need to use dialog to create terminal GUI". The word GUI probably doesn't mean what you think it means.

Comment: @4ae1e1 GUI graphical user interface